# Error in creating EC2 resource using Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to create an EC2 using terraform (I'm new to the area). I'm following the tutorial, but I think there's something wrong with the user I created in AWS.

Steps I followed:

1. Create user in AWS
   a) I added to a group that has the AmazonEC2FullAccess policy
   b) I created the credentials to use the AWS Cli
2. I used the file suggested by the Terraform tutorial

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

3. I ran the aws configure command and put the key and secret key values.
4. I ran terraform init and it worked
5. When I run the terraform plan, the error appears.

```
Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you have a typo in your API keys you entered in the `aws configure` step. I suggest testing with a simple AWS CLI command first, like `aws s3 ls` to make sure you have the credentials configured correctly before moving on to work with Terraform.

Comment: Could you please run this command `aws sts get-caller-identity` to verify if you really authenticated with AWS with the user you created? It will give you the UserID, Account, and Arn of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the parameter "profile" in main.tf. So, the new file is

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
  profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-0557a15b87f6559cf"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

Its works now!